# Save Custom Meta Value on Media Upload

Tags: custom-field, uploads, media, media-library

I am looking for an option where a custom meta value will be saved when user uploads an attachment.

Lets say I need a meta key _example_meta_key and want to save meta value of this as ex087659bh (It will be a randomly generated number, I can take care of this.)

However, The problem is, I can't seem to find any filters to add custom meta value on upload. There are some tutorials which shows the way to add fields in media edit form but I need this to be executed at the time of file upload.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you referring to admin area uploading or do you have custom frontend uploading via `media_handle_upload()`?

Comment: Core admin pages. I am just trying to alter the media upload process, so it saves an additional post meta when it processes the upload.

Answer (score 0):

If you are uploading via Core admin pages, WordPress will most likely upload the file, and then create an `attachment` post-- that is, a post with the `attachment` post type. So the [`save_post_attachment`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4/src/wp-includes/post.php#L3374) hook might do it for you.

```
3362            /**
3363             * Fires once a post has been saved.
3364             *
3365             * The dynamic portion of the hook name, `$post->post_type`, refers to
3366             * the post type slug.
3367             *
3368             * @since 3.7.0
3369             *
3370             * @param int     $post_ID Post ID.
3371             * @param WP_Post $post    Post object.
3372             * @param bool    $update  Whether this is an existing post being updated or not.
3373             */
3374            do_action( "save_post_{$post->post_type}", $post_ID, $post, $update );
```

It is hard to be very specific given how general the question is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll give it a try and let you know.